# Entity Framework GroupBy to Sql Generation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I stuck with performance problem with EF.

```
        using (var context = new CustomDbContext())
        {
            var result = context.
                TransactionLines
                .Where(x => 
                    x.Transaction.TransactionTypeId == 1433 &&
                    (x.Transaction.Eob.EobBatchId == null || x.Transaction.Eob.EobBatch.Status == EobBatchStatusEnum.Completed)
                )
                .GroupBy(x => x.VisitLine.ProcedureId)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Id = x.Key,
                    PaidAmount = x.Sum(t => t.PaidAmount),
                    Code = context.Procedures.Where(h => h.Id == x.Key).Select(h => h.Code).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToArray();
        }
```

EF generate the next sql:

```
SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[Project6].[ProcedureId] AS [ProcedureId], 
[Project6].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project6].[C1] AS [C3]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project5].[ProcedureId] AS [ProcedureId], 
    [Project5].[C1] AS [C1], 
    (SELECT 
        SUM([Extent7].[PaidAmount]) AS [A1]
        FROM     [dbo].[TransactionLines] AS [Extent7]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Transactions] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent7].[TransactionId] = [Extent8].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Eobs] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[EobId] = [Extent9].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[EobBatches] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent9].[EobBatchId] = [Extent10].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[VisitLines] AS [Extent11] ON [Extent7].[VisitLineId] = [Extent11].[Id]
        WHERE (([Extent9].[EobBatchId] IS NULL) OR (1 = [Extent10].[Status])) AND ([Extent8].[TransactionTypeId] = 1433) AND (([Project5].[ProcedureId] = [Extent11].[ProcedureId]) OR (([Project5].[ProcedureId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent11].[ProcedureId] IS NULL)))) AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project4].[ProcedureId] AS [ProcedureId], 
        [Project4].[C1] AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project2].[ProcedureId] AS [ProcedureId], 
            (SELECT TOP (1) 
                [Extent6].[Code] AS [Code]
                FROM [dbo].[Procedures] AS [Extent6]
                WHERE [Extent6].[Id] = [Project2].[ProcedureId]) AS [C1]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Distinct1].[ProcedureId] AS [ProcedureId]
                FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                    [Extent5].[ProcedureId] AS [ProcedureId]
                    FROM     [dbo].[TransactionLines] AS [Extent1]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Transactions] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TransactionId] = [Extent2].[Id]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Eobs] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[EobId] = [Extent3].[Id]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[EobBatches] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[EobBatchId] = [Extent4].[Id]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[VisitLines] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[VisitLineId] = [Extent5].[Id]
                    WHERE (([Extent3].[EobBatchId] IS NULL) OR (1 = [Extent4].[Status])) AND ([Extent2].[TransactionTypeId] = 1433)
                )  AS [Distinct1]
            )  AS [Project2]
        )  AS [Project4]
    )  AS [Project5]
)  AS [Project6]
```

The query duration is ~3 seconds.
If write sql query directly using Group By then a query duration is 1.5 seconds and it use half less CPU resources.

```
    SELECT sq.ProcedureId, SUM(sq.PaidAmount), (SELECT TOP(1) Procedures.Code From Procedures Where Procedures.Id = sq.ProcedureId) as Code
FROM(
    SELECT [Extent5].[ProcedureId] AS [ProcedureId],[Extent1].PaidAmount as [PaidAmount]
    FROM     [dbo].[TransactionLines] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Transactions] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TransactionId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Eobs] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[EobId] = [Extent3].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[EobBatches] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[EobBatchId] = [Extent4].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[VisitLines] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[VisitLineId] = [Extent5].[Id]
    WHERE (([Extent3].[EobBatchId] IS NULL) OR (1 = [Extent4].[Status])) AND ([Extent2].[TransactionTypeId] = 1433)
) sq
GROUP BY sq.ProcedureId
```

I wrote different linqs but still can't force EF generate GroupBy instead of subqueries.
Ideally, i wouldn't want to use functions or manually written sql, because I have a lot of conditions in building linq logic.

Is it possible to force EF to generate SQL exactly as it was written within linq ?

Comment: First try to rewrite your LINQ query using explicit joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try avoiding the

```
context.Procedures.Where(h => h.Id == x.Key).Select(h => h.Code).FirstOrDefault()
```

by including the `Code` in the `GroupBy` clause - I know it seems redundant, but EF is known to have problems translating operations on grouping that involve something other than using key accessors and aggregates:

```
//...
.GroupBy(x => new { Id = x.VisitLine.ProcedureId, x.VisitLine.Procedure.Code })
.Select(x => new
{
    Id = x.Key.Id,
    PaidAmount = x.Sum(t => t.PaidAmount),
    Code = x.Key.Code
}).ToArray();
```

**Update:** the above generates the following SQL in my test environment (latest EF6.1.3):

```
SELECT
    1 AS [C1],
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [ProcedureId],
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2],
    [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [Code]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Extent5].[ProcedureId] AS [K1],
        [Extent6].[Code] AS [K2],
        SUM([Filter1].[PaidAmount]) AS [A1]
        FROM    (SELECT [Extent1].[VisitLineId] AS [VisitLineId], [Extent1].[PaidAmount] AS [PaidAmount]
            FROM    [dbo].[TransactionLine] AS [Extent1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Transaction] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TransactionId] = [Extent2].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Eob] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[EobId] = [Extent3].[Id]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[EobBatch] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[EobBatchId] = [Extent4].[Id]
            WHERE (1433 = [Extent2].[TransactionTypeId]) AND ([Extent3].[EobBatchId] IS NULL OR [Extent4].[Status] = 1) ) AS [Filter1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[VisitLine] AS [Extent5] ON [Filter1].[VisitLineId] = [Extent5].[Id]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Procedure] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[ProcedureId] = [Extent6].[Id]
        GROUP BY [Extent5].[ProcedureId], [Extent6].[Code]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

which is much better as I expected.

**Update 2:** EF is a strange beast. Using double projection produces the desired result:

```
//...
.GroupBy(x => x.VisitLine.ProcedureId)
.Select(x => new
{
    Id = x.Key,
    PaidAmount = x.Sum(t => t.PaidAmount),
})
.Select(x => new
{
    x.Id,
    x.PaidAmount,
    Code = context.Procedures.Where(h => h.Id == x.Id).Select(h => h.Code).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToArray();
```

which produces the following:

```
SELECT
    1 AS [C1],
    [Project2].[ProcedureId] AS [ProcedureId],
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C2],
    [Project2].[C2] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1],
        [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [ProcedureId],
        (SELECT TOP (1)
            [Extent6].[Code] AS [Code]
            FROM [dbo].[Procedure] AS [Extent6]
            WHERE [Extent6].[Id] = [GroupBy1].[K1]) AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent5].[ProcedureId] AS [K1],
            SUM([Filter1].[PaidAmount]) AS [A1]
            FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[VisitLineId] AS [VisitLineId], [Extent1].[PaidAmount] AS [PaidAmount]
                FROM    [dbo].[TransactionLine] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Transaction] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TransactionId] = [Extent2].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Eob] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[EobId] = [Extent3].[Id]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[EobBatch] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[EobBatchId] = [Extent4].[Id]
                WHERE (1433 = [Extent2].[TransactionTypeId]) AND ([Extent3].[EobBatchId] IS NULL OR [Extent4].[Status] = 1) ) AS [Filter1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[VisitLine] AS [Extent5] ON [Filter1].[VisitLineId] = [Extent5].[Id]
            GROUP BY [Extent5].[ProcedureId]
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
    )  AS [Project2]
```

P.S. If it's unclear, the answer to your concrete question

> Is it possible to force EF to generate SQL exactly as it was written within linq ?

is no. Contrary, you should write LINQ query in a certain way in order to get the desired (or closer) SQL query.

Comment: Adding second column to group by does not force EF to generate GroupBy, it add additional column to subqueries and add additional filters to them which  significantly  decrease the performance with current query. Using subquery for procedure code is much better in my case

Comment: And the problem isn't with obtaining code from procedure, but with EF that generate
few subqueries with same filters , that is much less efficient than using GroupBy approach.

Comment: I'm not saying subquery is inefficient - I'm trying to use LINQ construct which will not cause EF to generate unnecessary subqueries. Are you sure the suggested modification does not translate to much better SQL? I can't test because don't have the model classes.

Comment: Yes, I know it because my first linq implementation was written using this 2 columns in groupBy. The sql query is the same.

Comment: Thanks.
Double select is produced desired result. Strange behavior. I think, will be useful to examine the source code of translator which convert DbExpressions to SQL